# The function parameter of jquery .val() returns the function as a string

Tags: jquery

As part of an onClick event, the value of each of the clicked row's subsequent siblings' hidden "sequence" inputs is reduced by one.

```
$('#variants_' + product + ' .sequence')
    .filter(function(){
        return parseInt(this.value, 10) > sequence;
    })
    .val(function(index, value){
        return value - 1;
    });
```

The inputs I'm trying to change end up looking like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="v_sequence_6" id="v_sequence_6" value="function (index, value){
                    return value - 1;
                    }" class="sequence">
```

How can I use the function parameter of .val() without it being turned into a string?

**edit**
here's the rest of the relevant function

```
function deleteVariant(row, product) {
var x = /x/
var sequence = $('#variantRow_' + row + ' .sequence').val();
if (! x.test(row) ){
    $('#variants_' + product).closest('#variants').append("<div class='grayover'><div class='ajaxLoaderContainer'><div class='ajaxLoader'><img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /></div></div></div>");

    $.post('includes/_e-learning_ajax.php', { 'mode': 'deleteVar', 'variant': row }, function(data){
        if (data == 'success'){
            $('#variants_' + product + ' .sequence')
                .filter(function(){
                    return parseInt(this.value, 10) > sequence;
                    })
                .val(function(index, value){
                    return value - 1;
                    });
            $('#variantRow_' + row).remove();
            coursesReady();
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
        $('.grayover').remove();
    });

} else {
    $('#variantRow_' + row).remove();
}
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue; can you post more of your HTML/JavaScript?

Comment: Are you sure you have a version of jQuery >= 1.4? That's the version that was introduced

Comment: Yeah, 1.6.x. I posted the rest of the function.

Comment: You're absolutely sure? It all seems fine to me... If you alert `jQuery.fn.jquery;` it will say 1.6.x

Comment: @user1494870 Why do you need the function as value ?

Comment: @Ricardo because each .sequence input the .filter() lets through will have a different value and that value needs to be reduced by 1 in each of them. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @user1494870 There's not a _better_ way to do it necessarily...but try something like this to make sure something can work: http://jsfiddle.net/Tjcku/

Comment: @Ian Ah, you got me. 1.3.2. My jQuery library says it's 1.6.2, so I don't know who put what where to cause that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Haha silly people. I added an answer for future visitors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your version of jQuery is less than 1.4, which is when the function passing version of the `val` method was introduced (what we determined from the conversation in your comments). That does make sense as the `val` method would be calling `toString` on the function that was being passed and was printing it fully as the input's value.

This can be shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hhk7T/